# Can this be site be constructed on WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, content-management-system, e-commerce

I have been approached by someone looking to build a website and was wondering if I could ask the community's advice on how to proceed given I am new to full stack web development.

The website requires :

- Visitors to be able to create their own accounts which will have
  differing permissions.
- Visitors to create their own pages on the website.
- An on-site search engine to search through these pages amongst other lists of elements.
- The ability to connect with multiple API's including ones I custom build.
- On site E-Commerce capabilities
- Hosted message boards/forums for "logged in" visitors to use/create/comment on etc.
- A content management system

I understand this is an absolutely massive project but I would mainly be creating for enjoyment. My question is, can all these features be implemented by creating the site in word press or will I have to build it from scratch and if so what backend stack would you recommend (I have some experience with NodeJS/express etc and hear keystone JS is a useful library for building a CMS).

Answer (score 0):

That is a massive one of course. Readymade ones like WordPress have limitations, and for this kind of a huge project, customizing wordpress can be tougher than making from scratch on your own. If you are comfortable with php, javascript  and mysql, all these, and any huge or small, applications can be made without any hassle, and without any additional fancy platforms and libraries.

Comment: Yeah, but, That is what the philosophy I stand for. I consider most of the techies around the globe are, while they preach nanoseconds speed and bandwidth optimization, in fact they are bloating the webpages and applications with unnecessary frameworks and plugins. For every basic functionality they go for plugin help, perhaps deploying a hydrogen bomb to kill a mosquito. I am a proponent of Code Simplification. Also I believe Additional Frameworks :-) and plugins corrode our techie-brain

Comment: ***if you develop your own framework*** not true, IF we were accumulating modular knowledge and code over time. :-)  ***the quality of that framework will be not as good as a framework that was a collaborative effort of hundreds of skilled developers*** :Not Necessarily true. Hundreds of Skilled Developers' works need Not be better than Our own tested+proved+collected modules, and a bit of commonsense how to put them together .  ***You can customize a framework by removing code that you do not need***  Most developers dont do that. They use entire stuff, because cannot be sure where a ...

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you do this in WordPress? A lot of the infrastructure you desire is already in place. Also with some free plugins, as well as few premium (pay) plugins that I can think of off the top of my head, most of what you list is already developed for WordPress. For me, when I build a WordPress site, the question I ask myself with regards to plugin use is, "If there's a quality plugin that does the job as I need, and I couldn't build a similar function in a reasonable timeframe vs cost of the plugin, then why not use one?"